# Search and replace text pattern

Tags: json, replace, jq

I am looking for a way to search/replace portion of the text in some of the values. In this example, I am looking to search for "abc" and replace with "xyz".

I tried this command without any luck:

```
jq -r '.[].name | |= if . contains("abc") then . = gsub("abc","XYZ") else . end' testfile
```

---

```json
[
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "abctext123",
    "module_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "id": 223,
    "name": "abcanothertext789",
    "module_name": "yyyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "anypattern",
    "module_name": "zzzzzzzzzzz"
  },
  {
    "id": 223,
    "name": "anothertest",
    "module_name": "anothervalue"
  }
]
```

Expected output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "XYZtext123",
    "module_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "id": 223,
    "name": "XYZanothertext789",
    "module_name": "yyyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "anypattern",
    "module_name": "zzzzzzzzzzz"
  },
  {
    "id": 223,
    "name": "anothertest",
    "module_name": "anothervalue"
  }
]
```

Comment: When calling `gsub/2`, you need to use a semicolon between the two arguments, e.g. `gsub(E;F)`

Answer (score 3):

No need for "contains". If there's no `abc`, it won't be replaced.

```
[ .[] | .name |= gsub("abc"; "XYZ") ]
```

or, shorter and cleaner using `map`:

```
map(.name |= gsub("abc"; "XYZ"))
```

If the condition is different, the correct syntax is

```
map(.name |= if contains("abc") then gsub("abc"; "XYZ") else . end)
```

or

```
[ .[] | .name |= if contains("abc") then gsub("abc"; "XYZ") else . end ]
```